# Website to check page rank based on keyword

Tags: pagerank

I'm wondering is there any way to check google page rank of a page of my website/blog based on a search keyword?

And not just the page rank, but the position/page.

For example, if I have a blog about "Lady Gaga Album Review", then if I search google with the keyword "Lady Gaga Album Review", I wanna know the actual position of my blog (for example, rank #43, page 4, or something like that)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a page with free google tools that you can use for SEO:

http://www.seoptimise.com/blog/2009/12/10-free-google-seo-tools-everybody-should-use.html

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there is such a thing, but this comes very close and is free:

> http://www.keyrow.com/